Angular form control ambiguous state
I'm trying to investigate why the control is marked as dirty at its initialization and what I see in the browser console is very confusing. The form control is either "dirty" OR "pristine", depending on how I log information to the console. It's such a pain, lol. How can this be the case?
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const control = this.form.get(this.controlName);
    console.log('TEST 1', control)
    console.log('TEST 2', control.dirty, control.pristine);
  }

Result


(...) in the devtools indicates that the values are lazily evaluated. Which means the value is only evaluated after click. So this screenshot is not very helpful. Can you create a minimal reproducible example in StackBlitz? It seems like after ngOnOnit ran, there is some action happening which marks the form as dirty.

@JSONDerulo you are right. There was an issue with change detection and form.  After I fixed it there is no more mismatch in the console.  Thanks!
